# Matlab code - Keep leading zero while extracting numerical data as string from .CSV

Tags: string, matlab, csv, import, xlsread

I have data stored in CSV format.The data contains numerical values formatted as text but written without any apostrophe.

[image: Sample]

I've tried to export the data using xlsread, bu Matlab automatically remove the leading zero. Is it possible to force Matlab to read it as string to keep the leading zero?

Comment: You might need to use something like `textscan` which allows for more precise control of format.

Comment: Can you share some actual CSV example data as text? The screencap you posted looks like an Excel screenshot, and Excel does weird formatting things that obscure the original underlying input format.

Answer (score 0):

xlsread has three outputs, the third bering the raw data. Use the third output, you will find the text there. Then you can convert the text to numeric data using str2num.

Comment: I've tried this, but the third / raw data also detect it as numerical and automatically remove leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a CSV file, don't use `xlsread`. That's for Excel (`.xls`/`.xlsx`) files. If the base data is primarily actually in an Excel file, then don't save it to CSV; read the Excel file directly.

You're going to have to use a lower-level read routine like `textscan` or `fscanf` to read this in. The issue is that CSV files don't actually represent strings and numbers differently: CSV files *only* contain text data, so programs like Matlab that work like numbers have to provide some "magic" to decide what things look like numbers and convert those strings into numbers. And they figure that you don't care about stuff like leading zeroes, so they abstract that away. But in this case you *do* care, so you have to bypass their magic.

Don't worry; `textscan` and `fscanf` are easy to use.

Do something like this:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.csv');
col_vals = textscan(fid, '%s');
orig_policy_num = col_vals{1};
fclose(fid);
```

Terminology note: you say "The data contains numerical values", but numerical values represent numbers, and leading zeros are insignificant for numbers; that's just a matter of different styles in which the same value can be written. But you care about leading zeros. That means this is actually *text* data, not numeric data. And you want to read it as such.